# `apollo-link-state` and `vuex`,which one should I use for state management when I use `vue-apollo`?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-apollo

`apollo-link-state` and `vuex`,which one should I use for state management when I use `vue-apollo`?

https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo

Answer (score 1):

Hey i just came across this issue with a project i was working on.

I don't think it really matters what one you use they both do the same thing in a different way. You might want to compare file sizes though as i did not.

Vuex is pretty straight forward compared to apollo-link-state IMO. I didn't want to figure out how to write resolvers in the FE code.

In the end I ended up going with Vuex just because i was familiar with it.